# Printing OpenStreetMap tiles to PDF

Tags: openstreetmap, pdf

What I would like to achieve is an A4 print out of an OSM map with a polygon outline printed on top.

This would come from a web application. Where a user can centre the map, upload a polygon. Which I can do already using Leaflet.js and Mapbox.

I have no idea where to start on this, but I need to take the tiles from the current "view" which would be easy enough, but then I need to scale them, draw the polygon ontop, and then print to a PDF which gets emailed back.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this in an automated way?

Comment: GDAL seems to have most components for the task. Read the PDF manual page http://www.gdal.org/frmt_pdf.html and the linked tutorial. Could be tricky to make a web application through that route, though.

Comment: As a starting point, I'd say take a look at the various tools listed on this page: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_on_Paper A few of them generate PDFs (Some *vector*, which is more advanced but better for print quality) You could poke around in the source code of existing apps and contact the developers.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to do this on the Client by copying the generated WMS Layers from Open Layers to a HTML5 Canvas.

I have not actually done it yet, but the resultant image could be saved, printed, etc using the standard browser controls.

I know you mention Leaflet, but it may be worth a look ..

A good article on this can be seen [Here!](http://blogs.edina.ac.uk/category/openlayers-html5-canvas/)